# What is session variable in android java?

Tags: java, android, session-variables

I am self-leaner to android and java.Is there any session variables available in android java? If so please let me know about its purpose and process.If possible with samples.

Thanks for your precious time!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When talking about session what do you mean by session

Because if you talk about Session to store login credentials or user information.

It may be a [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

and if you talk about temporary data storage, like data downloaded from internet or another application related data, which is intended to be shared throughout the application can be shared using many means like [`Application` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), `static` variable, [`File` IO](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), [`Sqlite`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't have session variables that I am aware of.  However, if your Android app is communicating with a web server, your app can make use of the PHP session variables on the web server.  Here is how:

1) Android app sends user's login credentials to your web server (www.your-web-server.com/login.php)
2) login.php checks the credentials and then calls `session_start()` to begin a session.
3) login.php then calls something like this: `my_current_session = session_id();` in order to get the session ID of the current session.
4) login.php then sends the session ID (`my_current_session`) back to the Android app.  I recommended echoing the session ID as a JSON-encoded string (json_encode).
5) The Android app stores the session ID locally.  You can stored it in SharedPreferences as some of the other answers have suggested.  Or you can store it in a [SQLite database locally on the device](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).
6) You can then include the session ID [in the Request Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793647/how-to-set-request-header-for-sending-data-from-android-apps-to-our-server) of all future GET and POST requests from the Android app to the web server.  The PHP running on the web server will recognize the session ID and make the associated session variables available.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need it.. There is application variables that get initialize during application start up. You can also make your singleton class to achive that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no api available to stored values in session rather you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), or can have static variables which can stored values which you want to save in session.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences.

You can find an [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)