# how to set request header for sending data from android apps to our server

Tags: java, android, json, http-headers

**How to set http header to sending json object from our android apps**
what type of header we want to use for sending data from client side to server.why we are using header and whats the importance in that one.

```
public class HomeLayoutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        private EditText value;
        private Button btn;
        private ProgressBar pb;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
            value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_layout, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                    // out of range
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
                }


        } 

        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postData(params[0]);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
                pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

            public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://floating-wildwood-1154.herokuapp.com/posts/create_a_post");

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", valueIWantToSend));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont know how to set request header for sending data from client side to server side.in my code how to set request header

Answer (score 17):

you can look into [this](http://hc.apache.org/)

you can use this

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost( "http://wwww.testserver.com/userAddMoney" );

post.addHeader( "X-Testing-Auth-Secret" , "kI7wGju76kjhJHGklk76" );
```

Comment: whats the inside the things you are mentioning @Mahaveer Muttha

Comment: @JitendraPatidar: these are the kay and values of your header dude.. please accept answers of you find useful..

Comment: httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); i used this one,is this correct,@Mahaveer Muttha

Comment: is this any library i want to add,or is this ok

Comment: @JitendraPatidar: Please go for some trial and error things.. use it as it is no need to add any library for HTTP things Android will take care of it..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805989/how-to-use-post-method-for-fetching-data-from-client-in-def-create-function-of-r  can you look at these question,here i metion full code@Mahaveer Muttha

Answer (score 6):

you can use

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            String getURL = "http://helloworld.com/getmethod.aspx?id=1&method=getData";
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(getURL);
            **httpGet .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-zip");**
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);  
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
            if (resEntity != null) {  
                        //parse response.
                        Log.e("Response",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thats for httpget,but i want to put in httppost,for http post also can i add that line

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://floating-wildwood-1154.herokuapp.com/posts/create_a_post");

// Add Headers
httppost.addHeader("key1", "value1");
httppost.addHeader("key2", "value2");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", valueIWantToSend));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: httppost.addHeader("key1", "value1");
httppost.addHeader("key2", "value2"); these two lines is enough ,could you tell me whats the use of add the header

Comment: see for example: http://www.androidadb.com/source/vuphone-read-only/projects/location-aware-calling/src/edu/vanderbilt/isis/trixbox/TrixboxManipulator.java.html

Comment: see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512188/setting-headers-in-post-request-with-java

Answer (score 0):

I coded a web services in .NET an then used ksoap2 in my android application to send data to my server.

Look at ksoap2-android:

http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html

I suggest to add this library:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.0.0/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

that carries also all dependencies.