# How to use post method for fetching data from client in def create function of ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, http, post

I am struggling with these question,how to fetch data from client side,how to use post method in def create function,to fetch the data from client side.
Client side coding is android,Server side code is ROR.

server side coding in ror

```
def create 
 respond_to do |format|

   @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully created."
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)

      format.json{ render :json => @post, :status => :created }
    else 
      flash[:notice] = "Error"
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 5)

      format.json{ render :json => @post, :status => :created }
    end
 end 
end

  def create_a_post 
   content = JSON.parse request.body.read 
     @post = Post.new[:content] 
      @post.save 
end
```

Here i create an new action as create_a_post for fetching,but what i felt is we have to fetch from def create function itself,whats the code is needed to fetch data.

**How to use def crate function,for getting data from client side**

Here i will mention my client side code also

```
public class HomeLayoutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        private EditText value;
        private Button btn;
        private ProgressBar pb;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
            value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_layout, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                    // out of range
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
                }


        } 

        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postData(params[0]);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
                pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

            public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://floating-wildwood-1154.herokuapp.com/posts/create_a_post");

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", valueIWantToSend));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question.. Your requirement doesn't seem clear.

Comment: @boddhisattva, i want to fetch data from client side,i have to do in def create function,but i dont know how to do,could your help me dude

Comment: Read the `params`. All data that was POSTed will be there.

Comment: @Zabba,how to do that one,i am not getting,could you edit my code and tell,i felt there is no need of adding an action  like create_a_post,we can fetch from create function itself,could your help me,i am struggling these part in two days

Comment: I am not an Android developer, but I can say that you need to see how to make a post request from Android to the server side create function. You can see if you could use curl or any http library for android that will will send a post request with the required params that will help create the post.

Comment: ya dude, i want only how to make post request form android to server side create function,bcz in client side i did it.from client side i am sending as content,what i want to add @boddhisattva

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Write down what you want to do, in steps: `1.` I click on X. `2.` Server receives Y. etc.

Comment: yes dude,in client side code also i mention from there they will send data,after that in server side they has to recive for this i wrote this code,could you check where my code is correct or not,i took this link as reference you can see this link also http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/ @Zabba

Comment: @boddhisattva, i put here my both client and server side code also,can   you look at my code

Comment: @Zabba, can you get my requirements,what are the mistakes i did,can you edit my code and give answer

Comment: @Zabba,whats the solution for my question,can you help me

Comment: @boddhisattva, are you there,what it might be the solution

Comment: As I said, I'm not an Android Developer.. I don't think I could assist you much on the code side..  You will have to just make sure your calling the server side action correctly from your client side. Good luck

Comment: @boddhisattva, dude my client side is code,i want to know only the server side code,can u check and tell how to write server side code for fetching data in def create function

Comment: @boddhisattva, you tell me how to write in server code alone,to fetch data from client side