# Call Async with multiple Http Post Method In Android

Tags: android

Request To guide me I know about json parsing in android and can read json object from direct url  such as can read information from http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/.

**Question:-**
I want to call API function by using Async Http Post Method

Method: POST
Api Key value Post each time to verify 
Verifylogin Post with parameters (How to pass with parameters)

My Api Code Is

```html
if ( $_POST['api_key'] == 'abc1239op3rt'  ) 
{
    if( $_POST['action'] == 'verifylogin')
 {
       if(trim($_POST['email']) == "") 
    {
     echo json_encode( array('status' => 'failure', 'message' => 'Please enter email address. ') );
     exit(0);
    }
     elseif(trim($_POST['password']) == "") 
    {
     echo json_encode( array('status' => 'failure', 'message' => 'Please enter password. ') );
     exit(0);
    }
    
     else{

     $result = verifylogin(  $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] );
     

     $status = ""; 
     if($result != false)
     {
      $data = $result;
      $message = "Login Successfully."; 
      $status = "success";
     }
     else
     {
      $data = $result;
      $message = "Error! Try again."; 
      $status = "failure"; 
     }
     echo json_encode( array('status' => $status, 'message' => $message,'data' => $data) );
     exit(0);
 }
  

 } 
}
```

Comment: Is this android code?

Comment: This might help: http://danielnugent.blogspot.com/2015/06/updated-jsonparser-with.html?m=1

Comment: Provided short piece of code is a API in PHP. I want to read this API through android Async Post Method. In Provided code 1ST has to check API KEY through post than Function (method) pass with parameters. Confuse about how multiple Post handle with Async Method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you need to set headers in your request. Go check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793647/how-to-set-request-header-for-sending-data-from-android-apps-to-our-server)